# View is not conquering full screen

Tags: android, view, android-activity, fullscreen

i want to implement full screen mode for activity.

so, i have used first:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.selector);
```

but that doesn't work. so i have deleted that code and used

```
<style name="Theme.CustomizedFullScreen" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

this code. But, for both code, the result is:

(Before implementing the code)
[image: Before implementing the code]

(After implementing the code)
[image: After implementing the code]

so, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

put layout_weight = "1" on in the xml of your layout.selector (this applys only if its in a linear layout, if its not, wrap it in one)
also set its parameters width and height to match parent

this will make the app recalculate the sizes of the views upon launch, after the request for window feature has been made